# Getting Username/Password authentication is no longer supported. Migrate to API Tokens or Trusted Publishers instead

Tags: python, pypi

When doing

```
python -m twine upload dist/*
```

in my computer I get:

```
Username/Password authentication is no longer supported. Migrate to API Tokens or Trusted Publishers instead.
```

I have in ~/pypirc the following data:

```
[distutils]
  index-servers =
    pypi
    cluster-experiments

[pypi]
  username = david26694
  password = pypi-XXXXX-

[cluster-experiments]
  repository = https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
  username = david26694
  password = pypi-XXXXX-
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message states correctly, Username/Password authentication is no longer supported.

You can add an API token in your [pypi account settings](https://pypi.org/manage/account/). Use the username `__token__` and `pypi-<YOUR TOKEN>` as password.

As the password in your example already have pypi-prefixes, I assume you already have generated API token. So all you need to do is change the username.

Your `~/pypirc` should look like this:

```
[distutils]
  index-servers =
    pypi
    cluster-experiments

[pypi]
  username = __token__
  password = pypi-XXXXX-

[cluster-experiments]
  repository = https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
  username = __token__
  password = pypi-XXXXX-
```